# How can I increase the height (size) and space between subplots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to have two equal size subplots and increase the height (size) of my third subplot. Also, my third plot sticks to my second subplot. I want to have a small distance between the second and the third subplots. I should mention that my X axis is common for all subplots. This is part of my code.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates

ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(date,amount, color='gray', linewidth=0.3)
plt.ylabel('2-4 Hz')

   
ax2 = plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(date,amount, color='brown', linewidth=0.3)
plt.ylabel('0.4-2 Hz')

ax3 = plt.subplot(313)
plt.bar (date, amount, color='gold', edgecolor='red', align='center')
plt.ylabel('rainfall(mm/day)')

ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2, ax3)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)


plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiLXG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this using the `gridspec_kw` argument in `plt.subplots()`, and then manually add a little space between the second and third axes. The `gridspec_kw` lets you set the height ratios of each axes.

There might be a better way to add the space between the second and third axis, but I think this meets your needs.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,1,2]})
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)
ax1 = ax[0]
ax2 = ax[1]
ax3 = ax[2]
bbox = list(ax3.get_position().bounds)
bbox[3] = 0.9*bbox[3] # Reduce the height of the axis a bit.
ax3.set_position(bbox)

ax1.plot(date,amount, color='gray', linewidth=0.3)
ax1.set_ylabel('2-4 Hz')

ax2.plot(date,amount, color='brown', linewidth=0.3)
ax2.set_ylabel('0.4-2 Hz')

ax3.bar (date, amount, color='gold', edgecolor='red', align='center')
ax3.set_ylabel('rainfall(mm/day)')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I changed my code according to your suggestion. The height has increased, as well as space between subplots, but my first two subplots have become empty, and the range of these two plots have changed. The range should be between (-2,2), while currently the range is (0,2) !

Comment: Please see the edited answer to see if that works for you.